# C# Return Type Issue

Tags: c#, python, .net, dllexport

I have a C# Class Library DLL that I call from Python.
No matter what I do, Python thinks the return type is (int)
I am using RGiesecke.DllExport to export the static functions in my DLL, here is an example of a function in my C# DLL:

```
[DllExport("Test", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]   
public static float Test()
{

    return (float)1.234;
}

[DllExport("Test1", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]   
public static string Test1()
{

    return "123456789";
}
```

If I return an (int) it works very reliably in Python.
Does anybody know what's going on?
This is my Python code:

```
    import ctypes
    import sys
    from ctypes import *

    self.driver = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(self.DLL)
    a= self.driver.Test()
```

Eoin

Comment: rather than return it like `return (float)1.234;` have you tried returning it like `return 1.2F`, also the float will only return as a single, giving you one decimal place.  You either want it as a double, decimal or an int

Comment: The solution is a little more complex than that I fear, I tried your suggestion now and no change. For now I don't care about precision, I just want any other return type than int

Comment: Can you return `string` or other non numeric types?

Comment: you could use directly pythonnet interop without all these manual wrapping code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is correct; as explained in the [ctypes documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#return-types), it is assumed that all functions return `int`s. You can override this assumption by setting the `restype` attribute on the foreign function. Here is an example using libc (linux):

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")
>>> libc.strtof
<_FuncPtr object at 0x7fe20504dd50>
>>> libc.strtof('1.234', None)
1962934
>>> libc.strtof.restype = ctypes.c_float
>>> libc.strtof('1.234', None)
1.2339999675750732
>>> type(libc.strtof('1.234', None))
<type 'float'>
```

Or a for a function that returns a C string:

```
>>> libc.strfry
<_FuncPtr object at 0x7f2a66f68050>
>>> libc.strfry('hello')
1727819364
>>> libc.strfry.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
>>> libc.strfry('hello')
'llheo'
>>> libc.strfry('hello')
'leohl'
>>> libc.strfry('hello')
'olehl'
```

This method should also work in your Windows environment.

Comment: Thanks you !! This works for double return type, I wil test the rest soon and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Just because the datatypes are given the same name doesn't mean that they are actually the same. It sounds as it python is expecting a different structure for what it calls a `"float"`.

This [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006119/c-sharp-ironpython-interop-and-the-float-data-type) may be of use, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560066/ironpython-c-float-data-comparison) states that a python `float` is a c# `double`; so my advice would be to try returning a `double` from your c# code.

Comment: That doesn't apply to my case I'm afraid, no matter what return type I use, Python always assumes it's an int